# Python 3 problema al crear fila de guiones (listas)

Tags: python-3.x

Muy buenas noches soy nuevo en esta comunidad y espero aprender y poder compartir todo lo que se (novato), queria crear una fila de guiones rellenando una lista, pero la salida del codigo es solo 1 guion S:

```
prueba=[]

palabra=["loquesea"]

for letra in range(len(palabra)):

   prueba.append("_")


print(prueba)
```

salida .... ['_']

Comment: Cual es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bye: @xtog

Podrías mejorar un poco el código, teniendo un **"input"** (entrada) para que así cualquiera ingrese una palabra (array) de diferente extensión de caracteres  y se guarde en la lista despues con el ciclo **for** se pinte de guiones o asteriscos dicha palabra:

```
palabra=input("ingrese su palabra:   ")
lista= [palabra]
for elemento in palabra:
     for letra in elemento:
          print ("*", end="")
```

saludos: espero que alguien le sirva :)

Comment: Gracias Andres ! eso esta faltando un abrazo amigo

Comment: puedes marcar como mejor respuesta para que destaque y asi  le pueda servir a los que están aun aprendiendo. un abrazo.                                                                   saludos

Answer (score 1):

al final pude resolverlo:

for letra in range(len(palabra))----> esta linea solo hace que el for se repita 1 vez porque la lista "palabra" tiene 1 elemento, lo que hice para sustituir todos los caracteres de "loquesea" por "-" (guiones) fue recorrer la lista palabras 2 veces, como en este ejemplo:

```
for elemento in palabra:
  for letra in elemento:
     print ("*", end="")
```

espero que a alguien pueda ayudar!

Comment: Pero esto no rellenaría una lista como pones en la pregunta, esto te devolvería ********

Comment: Puedes cambiar tu segundo bucle por print('*' * len(elemento))

Comment: Gracias adrian tenes razon, la formulacion de mi pedido estuvo mal hecha en mi caso solo mostre los asteriscos por cada uno de los caracteres de una palabra, lo cual no significa rellenar una lista nueva, asi que vale tu aclaracion :)

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en tu pregunta dices **quería crear una fila de guiones rellenando una lista**, es decir, entiendo que buscas esto (con asteriscos en vez de guiones): `['********']` o esto: `['*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*']` (en tu código al hacer `append` es lo que saldría si el código funcionase), de tu respuesta indicando que ya lo conseguiste se ve que lo que realmente quieres es solamente esto: `'********'`.

Como te he indicado en los comentarios, partiendo de `palabra = ["loquesea"]` podrías hacerlo simplemente así:

```
for elemento in palabra:
    print('*' * len(elemento))
```

O de una manera menos 'entendible', solamente con:

```
print(*map(lambda x: '*' * len(x), palabra))
```

Si sabes que tu lista solamente va a contener una palabra, o sabes el índice de la palabra a sustituir por asteriscos:

```
print('*' * len(list(palabra[0])))
```

En todos los casos devolvería   `********`